# .Net Core 2.x application hosted on server IIS "No authenticationScheme was specified"

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an .Net core web application, hosted on a Windows Server 2016 environment with .Net core installed.

I found after I included the filter in the ConfigureServices method within Startup.cs, publish into server IIS, run the application, I got an Http 500 error.

This is the code in my ConfigureServices and Configure method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

    services.AddDbContext<LocalAppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Global filter
            services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/StatusCode/{0}");

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Requests}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

in the log file, I see this on the top of all the stack output:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>   An unhandled exception has occurred: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

After some googling, it seems because no authenticationscheme is defined.

But above my services.AddMvc line, I have the AddAuthentication, which uses the IISDefaults authentication scheme:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Any idea what causes this 500 internal server error in my case?

Comment: I am sorry Kirk, your  updated code actually made some different in the error after I remove the initial services.Addauthentication lines. Here is the error: fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Windows
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Windows

Comment: It was my stupid mistake, the application in IIS didn't enable Windows Authentication, but with Anonymous Authentication by default.

Comment: That’s a more common mistake than you might think. I’m glad you’ve got it sorted. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You suggestions did give me some chance to know more about the methods inside Startup.cs file.

Answer (score 3):

The code in my question is correct.

It's a stupid mistake, I didn't enable Windows Authentication when I try to use domain account to authenticate the user access. By default Anonymous Authentication is used.